# Conda install dlib - PackageNotfoundError

Tags: python, dlib, anaconda3

Doing `conda update --all` and `conda install dlib`

gives this error:

> .2.2 - haa95532_296.tar.zst . You probably need to delete and re - download or re - create this file . Message from libarchive was : \ n
> \ nFile size could not be restored ' )
>
> ( myvenvpy ) ( base ) C : \ Users \ sir > Conda install dlib
>
> Collecting package metadata ( current_repodata.json ) : done
>
> Solving environment : failed with initial frozen solve . Retrying with flexible solve . collecting package metadata ( repodata.json ) : done
>
> Solving environment : failed with initial frozen solve . Retrying with flexible solve .
>
> PackagesNotFoundError : The following packages are not available from current channels :
>
> - dlib
>
> Current channels :
>
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>
> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're looking for , navigate to https://anaconda.org and use the search bar at the top of the page .
>
> ( myvenvpy ) ( base ) C : \ Users \ sir >

Screenshot of error: [Conda install dlib package not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OKDZ.jpg)

Comment: Hi Rushi, have you tried `.2.2 - haa95532_296.tar.zst . You probably need to delete and re - download or re - create this file`

Answer (score 0):

As per [Anaconda: dlib](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/dlib)

Try `conda install -c conda-forge dlib`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28867790)

Comment: Okay. Will keep this in mind for next replies. Do you want me to remove this answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this `pip install dlib`

or `python3 -m pip install dlib`

I think it will works for you

Answer (score 0):

I have a `dlib` installer inside a Dockefile (for OpenCV) that looks like this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y sudo && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

sudo chmod -R 777 ./

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y apt-utils build-essential cmake && sudo apt-get install -y libgtk-3-dev && sudo apt-get install -y libboost-all-dev && sudo apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev

pip install dlib
```

All of this because of the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your python version. Upgrade or downgrade python accordingly .
install cmake :- pip install cmake
install dlib :- pip install dlib

for anaconda :-
install cmake :-conda install -c conda-forge cmake
install dlib :- conda install -c conda-forge dlib